# Custom react code snippets not working in vscode in javascriptreact.json file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to add a few custom **React.js** code snippets in **VSCode**. I realize there are two files in **VSCode** for this. **javascript.json** and **javascriptreact.json**. **javascript.json** works just fine but when I move the snippets to **javascriptreact.json**, **VSCode** doesn't recognize them.

It'll be great if I could isolate these snippets in **javacriptreact.json** file because I also write server side JavaScript.

I'm guessing that **VSCode** doesn't recognize the app as a React app. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

save file with.jsx extension instead of .js. i.e. code snippets you are seeing in javascript.json is because you are editing a .js file

Answer (score 3):

I very recently was getting this issue in **Ubuntu 18.04**, after including the below code for my "react-classnames" snippet in vscode file (which was not giving me the expected result when I type inside a React file in vscode)

~/.config/Code/User/snippets/javascriptreact.json

```
  "react-classnames": {
    "prefix": "clmi",
    "body": [
      "className={classes.}"
    ],
    "description": "react-classname"
  },
```

So, in a React component .js file when I type the snippet ('clmi' in this case) - before the React Component File's return() statement, I get the expected behaviour.
But if I type the snippet ('clmi') inside the return() statement, I dont get anything. i.e. the snippet does not give me the code completion option inside the return () statment.

The source was that VSCode was not recognizing this file to be a "javascriptreact" language type.

**Solution was as below**

In a React Component's .js file, try the tokens inspector via "F1 > Inspect TM Scopes" and position the cursor at those insert position. That will tell you the detected, embedded language. Depending on your grammar it might be a different language

And bleow is what I am getting.
[image]

So as you can see, this not **JavaScript** nor **JavaScript React** but the **jsx-attr** language. So now I had to target that type with vscode snippet

So now, I put the whole snippet in the jsx-attr type target file
 `~/.config/Code/User/snippets/jsx-attr.json`

And now the custom snippets worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When I added the react snippet to jsx.json file the configuration worked. It did not work when added to js.json.

This worked:
`~/.config/Code/User/snippets/jsx.json`

This did not work:
`~/.config/Code/User/snippets/js.json`